# $k$ field with characteristic $p$, polynomial $x^{p^n} - 1$ obviously has a single root, what about $x^{pn} - 1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Lang's Algebra (VI. 3. Roots of unity); Lang actually never mentions this as far as I know:

If $k$ is a field with characteristic $p$, then the polynomial $x^{p^n} -1$ has only one root and that's 1, since this is actually just Frobenius endomorphism composited, so we can write
$$(x-1)^{p^n} = 0$$

What about a polynomial $f(x) = x^{pn} -1$ where $n$ is relatively prime to $p$? $1$ is a root, but $f' = 0$ implies that $1$ is the only root? This doesn't make sense since this polynomial can be simplified like this:
$$(x^n - 1)^p$$

and in a splitting field of separable polynomial $x^n -1$ we have $n$ distinct roots, so how is it  that we deduced that $1$ is the only root (since $f'=0$)? Where is the problem?

Comment: Why does $f'=0$ imply that there is only one root? That just the implies inseparability of $f$ in the case that $f$ is not constant.

Comment: $f'=0$ implies that $f$ has a root of multiplicity larger than $1$ at $1$.

Comment: @Arkady I thought this holds: if $f$ has a root $\alpha$ then $x-\alpha$ divides $f$. If $f'(\alpha)=0$, then $(x-\alpha)^2$ divides $f$ (multiplicity is at least 2). If $f^{(m)} =0$ (m-th derivative), then $(x-\alpha)^{m+1}$ divides $f$. So if $f'=0$, we have a single root. Where does this fail?

Comment: Please try to expand your sketch to a full argument. In characteristic $p$, it fails at the $p$-th derivative step.

Comment: Oh I see now, sorry, I will in the future. I see why it fails, it would be better if this was noted somewhere in the book